# On each click new button has been created. How should I create same functionality for new created buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

```
 var clicks = 0;
    function clickME() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;


    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode(clicks);

    btn.setAttribute("onClick", clicks);

    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);


 }
<button type="button" onClick="clickME(**strong text**)">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

This is the code that created new button with the counter. Now I want to implement same functionality for each of the new buttons. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
btn.setAttribute("onClick", clicks);
```

`clicks` is a **variable** which counts the clicks, **not** a function. You want to instead assign the function to the new button, like this:

```
btn.onclick = clickME;
```

Here's the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-frog-0qust